# @Id String id; is it the same with @Id ObjectId id? At least at the mongodb level?

Tags: mongodb

Due to the GWT nature of my application, I cannot use directly the `ObjectId` in my code, so I used:

`@Id String id;` instead. It the same with @Id ObjectId id? At least at the mongodb level? I mean in the way it is store, its format.

Also, is there a way to retrieve the documents based on relative location from a give String id or ObjectId? Like before or after a specific ObjectId?

Comment: How do you generate String id? You have to ensure that generated ids are increasing (as defined by mongo) if you want to have before/after queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Due to the GWT nature of my application, I cannot use directly the
>   ObjectId in my code

yes you can if you use [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) (and you're using RPC now).

> @Id String id; instead. It the same with @Id ObjectId id? At least at
>   the mongodb level? I mean in the way it is store, its format.

does this answer your question:

```
> db.foo.findOne({_id : ObjectId("4f156018ef7b8b0317a8ad18")})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f156018ef7b8b0317a8ad18"),
    "a" : 2,
    "b" : 4,
    "c" : 5,
    "d" : 1
}
> db.foo.findOne({_id : "4f156018ef7b8b0317a8ad18"})
null
> "4f156018ef7b8b0317a8ad18" == ObjectId("4f156018ef7b8b0317a8ad18")
true
>
```

> Also, is there a way to retrieve the documents based on relative
>   location from a give String id or ObjectId? Like before or after a
>   specific ObjectId?

yes, for example:

```
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f156018ef7b8b0317a8ad18"), "a" : 2, "b" : 4, "c" : 5, "d" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f156022ef7b8b0317a8ad19"), "a" : 4, "b" : 1, "c" : 3, "d" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f17e667ef7b8b0317a8ad1d"), "a" : 4, "b" : 1, "c" : 3, "d" : 2 }

> db.foo.find({_id : {$gt : ObjectId("4f156022ef7b8b0317a8ad19")}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f17e667ef7b8b0317a8ad1d"), "a" : 4, "b" : 1, "c" : 3, "d" : 2 }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The store format is not the same, for @Id String id, it's stored as:
   `{_id: "4f115016db84b77e57732f4a", ...}`, while for @Id Object id, it is `{_id: ObjectId("4f115016db84b77e57732f4a"), ...}`
2. _id field is always indexed. But it's quite hard to understand the semantic of "before"/"after" relationship between _ids. If it's uniquely generated UUID or ObjectID, that order might be completely in a random way in terms of String's compare function. What's your use case to use this order relationship?

Comment: I need to provide a facility similar to twitter, a timeline so I need to get documents "before" and "after"

Comment: then you probably need to give your model a `created` timestamp field and use that to index records